# Shell script curl limit the try time for page not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ksh, curl

I found following code to check web url.

```
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
  echo "URL exists: $url"
else
  echo "URL does not exist: $url"
fi
```

Here if the page not exist the script take long time to response. Is it possible to limit the time to wait for connection and skip?

Even alternative methods are ok.

Comment: Did you try `man curl | less -p timeout` ?

Comment: where to put the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the --max-time  option. You may also want to set --connect-timeout  which will limit the amount of time that curl tries to connect to the server.

Example: 
curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail --max-time 10 --connect-timeout 3 "$url"